# How to create an object if it does not exist in a nested form in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I need to create a `Training`, then add `Attendances` with nested form fields (cocoon) in a Rails 6 app. Here is the situation:

The models are the following:

**Training model**

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :people, through: :attendances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Attendance model**

```
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :training
  belongs_to :person
end
```

**Person model**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trainings, through: :attendances
end
```

If a `Person` exists in the database, then the user selects the person's name from a dropdown select field.

If the `Person` does not exist, then the user must enter the person's information manually by entering the name and age of the person.

**How do I set up the controllers and form to allow a user to manually enter the person's name and age, and then automatically create that person and the attendance in the nested form fields when the training is saved?**

Comment: This is one of the examples I describe here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms#the-look-up-or-create-belongs_to and is also demonstrated in the example project https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo

Comment: These links show how exactly to do it. For this case it is the last example for the has_many through example at the end of the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The key is having an `id` field for the nested attributes.  Rails's behavour is to update an existing record if the `id` is present, or to create a new record if the `id` is blank.

That, essentially, is all you need to do. Enter the person's name and age but leave the `id` empty, and a new record will be created.

I strongly recommend the `cocoon` gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon which will give you a `link_to_add_association` helper  for your training form that automatically lets you open a new, empty person form. When implemented you'll call the helper using something like this

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'add attendee', f, :people %>
```

You can ignore that the person is associated to the training by a join table... rails will create the join record automatically when you save the new person.

Comment: Yes, but the case here is that my cocoon link is this: link_to_add_association 'add attendance', f, :attendances. So, I am creating an attendance (the join table in this case) and creating a person at the same time in the training form.

Comment: I think this requires the use of the first_or_create method

Comment: Don't do `f.attendance` do `f.people` you can ignore attendance and just add people.

Answer (score 0):

I used the link from the comment above: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms#the-look-up-or-create-belongs_to

And I used the last example in the wiki.

Here is how my final version of the MVC turned out for this feature:

The models

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trainings, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :training
  belongs_to :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Training < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :people, through: :attendances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
end
```

The trainings controller

```
class TrainingsController < ApplicationController
    
    put your normal controller actions here and then in 
    training_params put this:

    def training_params
      params.require(:training).permit(
        attendances_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :person_id, person_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name, :age, :program_id]]
      )
    end
end
```

Add this to the trainings/_form

```
  .row
    .col.s12
      .pt-5
        %h6
          Attendance
      #people
        = f.fields_for :attendances do |attendance|
          = render 'attendance_fields', :f => attendance
        .people_links
          = link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :attendances
```

Add this to trainings/_attendance_fields

```
.nested-fields.attendance-person-fields
  .field
     .person_from_list
       = f.select(:person_id, Person.all.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, { include_blank: true }, { :class => 'chosen-select' })
     = link_to_add_association 'Or create', f, :person, data: {disable_with: "creating person"}
```

Finally in trainings/_person_fields

```
.nested-fields
  .input-field
    = f.text_field :name
    = f.label :name
  .input-field
    = f.number_field :age
    = f.label :age
```

I added coffee script :( in: person.coffee

```
  $('#people').on('cocoon:before-insert', (e, attendance_to_be_added) ->
    attendance_to_be_added.fadeIn 'slow'
    return
  )

  $('#people a.add_fields').data('association-insertion-position', 'before').data 'association-insertion-node', 'this'
  
  $('#people').on 'cocoon:after-insert', ->
    
    $('.attendance-person-fields a.add_fields').data('association-insertion-position', 'before').data 'association-insertion-node', 'this'
    
    $('.attendance-person-fields').on 'cocoon:after-insert', ->
      
      $(this).children('.person_from_list').remove()
      $(this).children('a.add_fields').hide()

      return
    return
```